# The Url method of IPublishContent is sometimes relative and sometimes absolute

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a site in Umbraco 7.7.2 and I need to take the relative Url my pages. I use the method Url and it works on my machine but when I upload my code to my production (on Azure-cloud configuration) it returns the absolute Url instead :|. what should I do?

My site's structure is simple so I have access to those specific pages like this:

```
var umbraco = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
var startPage= umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().First();
var specificPage= startPage.FirstChild(c => c.IsDocumentType("specificPage"));
var url= specificPage.Url; // returns relative address on my local and absolute url on cloud
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL it returns depends on the hostnames configured for the site, and the setting in /config/umbracoSettings.config.

In umbracoSettings.config you can set the "useDomainPrefixes" property to true which tells Umbraco to include the domains in the URLs it generates. Is that set n live?

The other thing to check is if the Hostnames are set on the home node in the back office.

When you say relative, do you mean root relative? E.g. /my-page/ as opposed to http://example.com/my-page/? As far as I know Umbraco shouldn't return actual relative links to the page you're on.